# Ranking yarn's running application by size

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, jq

I came up with a way to list yarn's running applications by size. Because size is divided into Allocated MB and Allocated VCores I decided to assume a VCore is about 10000 MB.

```
# Uses httpie and jq, or you could use curl with -H Content-Type:application/json
http http://yarn-web-ui-url:port/ws/v1/cluster/apps|jq '
  .apps.app 
  | sort_by(.allocatedMB + .allocatedVCores * 10000) 
  | reverse 
  | .[] 
  | select(.state == "RUNNING") 
  | {name, allocatedMB, allocatedVCores, user, id, trackingUrl}' | 
  less
```

But is there some way to do this in the UI directly? And if not does anyone see a more effective way to write the JQ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does anyone see a more effective way to write the JQ part

For efficiency, it would be better to make the selection before the sort.  Your filter can also be slightly simplified:

```
  .apps.app 
  | map(select(.state == "RUNNING"))
  | sort_by(.allocatedMB + .allocatedVCores * 10000) 
  | reverse[] 
  | {name, allocatedMB, allocatedVCores, user, id, trackingUrl}
```

Comment: I was relatively new to `jq` and didn't see map as an option. Also putting the array operator onto reverse didn't seem like an option in the docs. Thanks!